# Hide Products from list based on authorization using cancan in rails_admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, cancan, rails-admin

I have a `Product` model.

`Ability` class is as follows:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user.has_role? :super_admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Product, Product.all.limit(10) if user.has_role? :brand_manager
      can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
      can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code for `rails_admin`:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with :cancan
 end
```

I want to hide all the `products` from list which don't have particular `name`? Some how `rails_admin` does not support it. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.
 1. Create a new field in  model like admin_user_id 
 2. While creating/updating  product from save current admin user details in product data
  and use it ability class

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability
 def initialize(user)
   if user.has_role? :super_admin
     can :manage, :all
   elsif user.has_role? :brand_manager
     can :manage,Product, :admin_user_id=> user.id
     can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
     can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome I get the one i want for it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with `hide all the producs from the list` ?

If you want that users can't read it, you can try:

```
can :read, Product do |product|
  [name1, name2].include?( product.name )
end
```

If you want don't return these products, you can use in your controller:

```
Product.where( :name.in => [name1, name2] )
```

I hope I've helped